# Trying to change @page url but getting an error

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I am learning Blazor, so I created a Blazor server app in Visual Studio 2019 (configured for SSL) and from the default template, opened "Counter.razor" in the "Pages" folder and changed "@page "/counter"" to "@page "/counterl"".

However when I start the application and go to "localhost:44336/counterl" the browser loads for a very long time and in the end errors out, saying "This site can’t be reached". The app is configured with the standard "Sorry, there's nothing at this address." for "NotFound" but that doesn't show.

How can I change the url at which a certain razor component/page is accessible?

The original razor thingy in question, "Counter.razor":

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be able to change the route that accesses the page by change the @page directive.  So, your approach seems fine.  Can you post the .razor page in full, so we can check?

Comment: Everything should be fine.  What happens if you change the page to "/counterl", then update the link in NavMenu.razor to <NavLink class="nav-link" href="counterl">, and then restart and click the link?  That should open your page.

Comment: @NeilW, I've removed the "NavMenu.razor" and tried to access the "/counterl" url by typing it by hand but it didn't work.

Comment: Just notice you said "The site can't be reached".  Did you start your app from Visual Studio and then change the URL in the browser that opens?  Or did you just open a browser window without starting the app in Visual Studio?  Did you type https before the url?  You mentioned that it is configured for SSL.  Right-click your server project and click 'properties'.  The window that opens will show you that there is one port for the App (no SSL) and another port for SSL.  Make sure you're using the right one.

Comment: @NeilW, I clearly said the app is configured to show "The site[...]" for "NotFound", however it does not do that in this case. I always start the app from Visual Studio and then change the URL in the browser that opens, I am using the ports in said "properties".